# How to check for unimported assets in React?

Tags: reactjs, assets

Is there a way to check if any assets in your src folder in your React app are not imported in any components?

Answer (score 1):

To check if there are any assets in your src folder that are not imported in any components, you can use the Webpack Bundle Analyzer. This tool generates a report that shows the contents of your app's bundle, including a list of all the assets that are included.

To use the Webpack Bundle Analyzer, you can follow the instructions in this blog post: https://blog.jakoblind.no/webpack-bundle-analyzer/

Once you have installed and configured the tool, you can run it to generate a report that shows the contents of your app's bundle. You can then use this report to see if there are any assets in your src folder that are not included in the bundle, which would indicate that they are not being imported in any of your components.